# Get bearer token for SharePoint server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, oauth

I'm developing a Windows 10 application for my company that runs on the client machine.

The app needs to make REST requests for our SP Server to get some information but as I have seen, I need an access token for the "Bearer" header of the request...

The SharePoint Server 2013 runs on our servers, and I have no idea how to get this bearer token...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I know it has something to do with OAuth but I can`t get to see how to configure our SP Server and my app for this!

I`m really stuck on this, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: check this once https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73d22947-0539-4f4c-ad8c-8e9c2adb84ef/remote-access-to-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-on-premises?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: In a book, i read that you have to register the app under /_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx however, the registration requires an app domain.. Since my app is not hosted in any domain, what value should I give?